# Mathematical Logic and Connectives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, logic

I wish to know if there is a formula using the connectives ⊕ and ¬ but no other connectives where the value of the formula depends on the placement of brackets? Thank you~

Comment: Can you give an example if what you have in mind as far as changing the placement if brackers goes?  How, in particular, do you think the $\neg$ would be involved with that?

Answer (score 2):

Since $(\neg p) \iff (p\oplus \top)$ and $\oplus$ is both commutative and associative, this shouldn't be possible.